# Add linux md raid write journal to and existing array

Tags: linux, mdadm, software-raid, raid5

I have a raid5 array with quite large disks, so reconstruction is really slow in case of a power outage. Thankfully, there is the `--write-journal` option for linux md raid. The man page lists the `--write-journal` option in the *For create, build, or grow:* section, so I supposed it should work in grow mode, and tried to add a write journal on the fly:

```
# mdadm --grow /dev/md1 --write-journal /dev/ssd/md1-journal
mdadm: :option --write-journal not valid in grow mode
```

Does anyone know whether I can add a write journal to an existing array? And if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It kind of should work like this:

```
# mdadm --manage /dev/md42 --readonly --add-journal /dev/loop3
mdadm: Journal added successfully, making /dev/md42 read-write
mdadm: added /dev/loop3
```

However, currently (using kernel 4.18, mdadm 4.1-rc) that only seems to be possible for arrays that were created with journal in the first place. The above output was procuded after:

```
# mdadm --create /dev/md42 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 /dev/loop[012] --write-journal /dev/loop3
mdadm: Defaulting to version 1.2 metadata
mdadm: array /dev/md42 started.
# mdadm --manage /dev/md42 --fail /dev/loop3 --remove /dev/loop3
mdadm: set /dev/loop3 faulty in /dev/md42
mdadm: hot removed /dev/loop3 from /dev/md42
```

Creating an array without journal, all attempts to add a journal fail:

```
# mdadm --create /dev/md42 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 /dev/loop[012]
mdadm: Defaulting to version 1.2 metadata
mdadm: array /dev/md42 started.
# mdadm --manage /dev/md42 --readonly --add-journal /dev/loop3
mdadm: /dev/md42 does not support journal device.
# mdadm --manage /dev/md42 --readwrite --add /dev/loop3
# echo journal > /sys/block/md42/md/dev-loop3/state
bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

So it just doesn't seem to be possible yet.

I have found [a discussion on the linux-raid mailing list](https://www.spinics.net/lists/raid/msg56116.html) that this is a planned feature. If it has been implemented since, I don't see how. Perhaps contact the mailing list yourself to remind mdadm devs there are people who want this to work!

You might have to resort to [`mdadm --create` to re-create the raid](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131927/30851) or edit metadata of the array. Either option is a bit dangerous.

Comment: I had to remove the internal bitmap before i was able to add a journal. mdadm --grow /dev/md42 --bitmap=none; echo resync > /sys/block/md42/md/consistency_policy; mdadm --manage /dev/md42 --add-journal /dev/loop3

Answer (score 0):

This PDF states it is possible: https://events.static.linuxfound.org/sites/events/files/slides/2016_vault_write_journal_cache_v2.pdf

`mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add-journal /dev/sdf`

Comment: Well, @frostschutz's answer already mentions the `--add-journal` option, as well as that it did not work yet in 1018. This answer really does not add to that by citing a 2016 presentation.

Answer (score 0):

The raid should be in read-only state. See --add-journal in
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mdadm.8.html

Try:
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --readonly --add-journal /dev/sdf

Comment: This does not work on debian stretch, I will try it on buster later. Do you know what version of mdadm and kernel this requires?

Comment: Doesn't work. I ended recreating my array (dangerous! backup!): mdadm --create /dev/md0 --assume-clean --level=5 --raid-devices=3 --write-journal=/dev/sdd2 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdb1 -k journal --bitmap=none

Comment: You have to do it in two commands. mdadm --readonly /dev/md0 then mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --addjournal /dev/sdf  ... don't forget it you already have a bitmap, you may have to remove that first.