# Problems with mdadm after resizing

Tags: ubuntu, mdadm, software-raid

I've had the same array for nearly 10 years and have been replacing disks with larger disks as the prices come down.

After my latest upgrade of 4 6TB disks in RAID 5 I have been having a strange issue. On every reboot, the array gets detected as a 4.4TB array. This is the very original size of my array. When the system is booted, I have to run `mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --size=max` and wait for a complete resync before the system is back to normal.

I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

I've followed these instructions each time I've upgraded the disks:

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --fail /dev/old_disk
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --remove /dev/old_disk
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/new_disk
```

I did this for each disk in the array and waited for the array to be healthy before moving on to the next disk. Once they were all replaced with larger disks, I ran `mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --size=max` and resized the filesystem. With the last upgrade, I had to enable 64-bit in ext4 to get over 16TB. That's the only difference.

Here's fdisk -l and /proc/mdstat output on first boot:

```
$ fdisk -l
Disk /dev/md0: 4.4 TiB, 4809380659200 bytes, 9393321600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 65536 bytes / 196608 bytes

$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid5 sdc1[3] sdb1[1] sdd1[0] sda1[2]
      4696660800 blocks level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]

unused devices: <none>
```

After running `mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --size=max`

```
$ fdisk -l
Disk /dev/md0: 16.4 TiB, 18003520192512 bytes, 35163125376 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 65536 bytes / 196608 bytes

$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid5 sdc1[3] sdb1[1] sdd1[0] sda1[2]
      17581562688 blocks level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      [=====>...............]  resync = 29.9% (1757854304/5860520896) finish=333.2min speed=205205K/sec

unused devices: <none>
```

```
$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 0.90
     Creation Time : Fri Dec 24 19:32:21 2010
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 17581562688 (16767.08 GiB 18003.52 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 18446744073709551615
      Raid Devices : 4
     Total Devices : 4
   Preferred Minor : 0
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Thu Apr 16 23:26:41 2020
             State : clean, resyncing 
    Active Devices : 4
   Working Devices : 4
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 64K

Consistency Policy : resync

     Resync Status : 33% complete

              UUID : 5cae35da:cd710f9e:e368bf24:bd0fce41 (local to host ubuntu)
            Events : 0.255992

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       49        0      active sync   /dev/sdd1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       2       8        1        2      active sync   /dev/sda1
       3       8       33        3      active sync   /dev/sdc1
```

/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf:

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# !NB! Run update-initramfs -u after updating this file.
# !NB! This will ensure that initramfs has an uptodate copy.
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR jrebeiro

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=0.90 UUID=5cae35da:cd710f9e:e368bf24:bd0fce41

# This configuration was auto-generated on Mon, 20 May 2019 04:28:45 +0000 by mkconf
```

I'm running mdadm - v4.1-rc1 - 2018-03-22 on Ubuntu 18.04.4 64-bit. I'm completely lost on this one.

UPDATE 1:

I've updated the metadata to 1.0 as suggested and now the array went back to 5TB and won't grow past that point.

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid5 sdc1[3] sdb1[1] sdd1[0] sda1[2]
      17581562688 blocks level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]

unused devices: <none>

$ sudo umount /mnt/array 
$ sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md0
mdadm: stopped /dev/md0
$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] 
unused devices: <none>
$ sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 --update=metadata /dev/sd[abcd]1
mdadm: /dev/md0 has been started with 4 drives.
$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid5 sdd1[0] sdc1[3] sda1[2] sdb1[1]
      4696660800 blocks super 1.0 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]

unused devices: <none>
$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.0
     Creation Time : Fri Dec 24 19:32:22 2010
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 4696660800 (4479.08 GiB 4809.38 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 1565553600 (1493.03 GiB 1603.13 GB)
      Raid Devices : 4
     Total Devices : 4
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Fri Apr 17 12:41:29 2020
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 4
   Working Devices : 4
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 64K

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : 0
              UUID : 5cae35da:cd710f9e:e368bf24:bd0fce41
            Events : 0

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       49        0      active sync   /dev/sdd1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       2       8        1        2      active sync   /dev/sda1
       3       8       33        3      active sync   /dev/sdc1
$ sudo mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --size=max
mdadm: component size of /dev/md0 unchanged at 1565553600K
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using archaic version 0.90 metadata.

From the `mdadm` manpage:

```
          0, 0.90
                 Use the original 0.90 format superblock.  This format
                 limits arrays to 28 component devices and limits
                 component devices of levels 1 and greater to 2 terabytes.

                 It is also possible for there to be confusion about
                 whether the superblock applies to a whole device or just
                 the last partition, if that partition starts on a 64K
                 boundary.
```

You really don't want a 2 terabyte per drive limitation.

Consider using `--update=metadata` on assembly.

```
          The metadata option only works on v0.90 metadata arrays and will
          convert them to v1.0 metadata.  The array must not be dirty
          (i.e. it must not need a sync) and it must not have a write-
          intent bitmap.
```

It would be better to migrate to 1.2 metadata instead (located 4K from start, instead of ~64K from end of drive), but that's more involved as all data will have to be relocated.

Comment: I'll try that. I have to wait until tomorrow for the sync to complete. I was curious if that was the issue or not.

Comment: This didn't work and now I'm afraid to go any further as it made the array back to 5TB and won't grow any further.

Comment: well.. it's officially game over. Someone on another forum suggested zeroing out the superblocks and recreating the array... but it by default created it with 1.2 metadata and wiped out the entire array. The good news is that it's now 16TB as expected... the bad news is that I lost all my data.

Comment: @JeffRebeiro a re-create is not necessarily completely lethal. even with wrong drive order / chunk size, raid5 xor results don't change. even if they did change it would usually only affect the last drive. just recreate with correct settings / missing drive according to examine output you posted above. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131927/30851

Comment: @JeffRebeiro dmesg of the persisting size issue might have been interesting

Comment: I haven't given up hope.. recreated the array with the 1.0 metadata and it's been rebuilding all day... almost done. And just as you said.. the last drive needed to be rebuilt. The only concern I have is that the 1.2 metadata is in a completely different location than 0.90/1.0 so there is likely some filesystem corruption.