# Can't mount extended logical partitions in RAID 0 Fake Array created by dmaid and device mapper

Tags: filesystems, raid, device-mapper, raid0, fakeraid

First of all, I would like to let you know I come here cause I'm looking for a solution or a way to be able to mount the HOME partition and to read the inside data.

I've been running Funtoo GNU/Linux on a **RAID 0 Fake Array** since I bought this computer in 2010, aprox.

Yesterday booted into **SystemRescue** and tried to format every partition **except HOME** part. and I think something went wrong while formatting cause suddenly I started suffering the following issue.

```
dmraid -ay
RAID set "isw_bggjiidefd_240GB_BX100v2_5" was activated
device "isw_bggjiidefd_240GB_BX100v2_5" is now registered with dmeventd for monitoring
RAID set "isw_cfccfdiidi_640GB_RAID0" was activated
device "isw_cfccfdiidi_640GB_RAID0" is now registered with dmeventd for monitoring
**ERROR: dos: partition address past end of RAID device**
RAID set "isw_bggjiidefd_240GB_BX100v2_5p1" was activated
RAID set "isw_bggjiidefd_240GB_BX100v2_5p2" was activated
RAID set "isw_bggjiidefd_240GB_BX100v2_5p3" was activated


ls /dev/mapper/
control                         isw_bggjiidefd_240GB_BX100v2_5p1  isw_bggjiidefd_240GB_BX100v2_5p3
isw_bggjiidefd_240GB_BX100v2_5  isw_bggjiidefd_240GB_BX100v2_5p2  isw_cfccfdiidi_640GB_RAID0
```

In the previous scheme and directory, **logical partitions inside the extended partition are missing**.

```
Disk /dev/mapper/isw_bggjiidefd_240GB_BX100v2_5p1: 300 MiB, 314572800 bytes, 614400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 16384 bytes / 32768 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/isw_bggjiidefd_240GB_BX100v2_5p2: 99.56 GiB, 106902323200 bytes, 208793600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 16384 bytes / 32768 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x73736572

Device                                             Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/mapper/isw_bggjiidefd_240GB_BX100v2_5p2-part1      1920221984 3736432267 1816210284   866G 72 unknown
/dev/mapper/isw_bggjiidefd_240GB_BX100v2_5p2-part2      1936028192 3889681299 1953653108 931.6G 6c unknown
/dev/mapper/isw_bggjiidefd_240GB_BX100v2_5p2-part3               0          0          0     0B  0 Empty
/dev/mapper/isw_bggjiidefd_240GB_BX100v2_5p2-part4        27722122   27722568        447 223.5K  0 Empty

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/mapper/isw_bggjiidefd_240GB_BX100v2_5p3: 450 MiB, 471859200 bytes, 921600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 16384 bytes / 32768 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6c727443

Device                                             Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/mapper/isw_bggjiidefd_240GB_BX100v2_5p3-part1      1634886000 3403142031 1768256032 843.2G 75 PC/IX
/dev/mapper/isw_bggjiidefd_240GB_BX100v2_5p3-part2      1936028160 3889681267 1953653108 931.6G 61 SpeedStor
/dev/mapper/isw_bggjiidefd_240GB_BX100v2_5p3-part3               0          0          0     0B  0 Empty
/dev/mapper/isw_bggjiidefd_240GB_BX100v2_5p3-part4        26935690   26936121        432   216K  0 Empty

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

[image: Gparted startup]
[image: Drive scheme in Gparted]
[image: Gparted Partition information]

Now, **using mdadm** instead of dmraid Fake RAID Tool.

Assembling the array through *mdadm* I can see every block device, but I can't mount HOME partition */dev/md/240GB_BX100v2.5_0p9*.
I can mount the other partitions under the extended partition because I formatted them when assembled by mdadm.

```
    mdadm --examine --scan
ARRAY metadata=imsm UUID=4f6eb512:955e67f6:5a22279e:f181f40d
ARRAY /dev/md/640GB_RAID0 container=4f6eb512:955e67f6:5a22279e:f181f40d member=0 UUID=1f9b13e6:b6dc2975:9c367bbb:88fa3d2b
ARRAY metadata=imsm UUID=c842ced3:6e254355:fed743f8:a4e8b8b8
ARRAY /dev/md/240GB_BX100v2.5 container=c842ced3:6e254355:fed743f8:a4e8b8b8 member=0 UUID=a2e2268c:17e0d658:17b6f16d:b090f250

ls /dev/md/
240GB_BX100v2.5_0    240GB_BX100v2.5_0p3  240GB_BX100v2.5_0p6  240GB_BX100v2.5_0p9  640GB_RAID0_0p2
240GB_BX100v2.5_0p1  240GB_BX100v2.5_0p4  240GB_BX100v2.5_0p7  640GB_RAID0_0        imsm0
240GB_BX100v2.5_0p2  240GB_BX100v2.5_0p5  240GB_BX100v2.5_0p8  640GB_RAID0_0p1      imsm1

mount /dev/md/240GB_BX100v2.5_0p9 /mnt/
mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md126p9, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

dmesg
[  179.400010] EXT4-fs (md126p9): bad geometry: block count 92565760 exceeds size of device (92565504 blocks)
```

But I can list every file using debugfs:

```
debugfs -c /dev/md126p9
debugfs 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
debugfs:  ls
 2  (12) .    2  (12) ..    11  (56) lost+found    1712129  (16) joan
 3670017  (12) tmp    4653057  (916) sys
```

[image: Home partition with mdadm & Gparted]

Comment: I'm not sure why the size is incorrect. You could try your luck with mdadm --build (but you have to get the settings right). Or you could tack on some blocks with dm-linear then hope for the best / shrink the filesystem a little. Or just grab the files with debugfs, maybe like this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/742453/30851 - afterwards consider getting rid of fakeraid/dmraid altogether. For raid0 in particular it's not worth the hassle...

Comment: Thanks, so much. Never had any problem for over 14 years been running this system. Through debugfs I can see all my files. Would you be able to provide some guidance on mdadm --build?

Comment: It would not help and it can go wrong... at this point, just take the files and run. Use either debugfs rdump, or pull an image with ddrescue, and make it larger by 256 blocks, loop mount it and hope for the best.

Comment: I'll go with ddrescue first, then with rdump. Do you know if I'll be able to keep the ownership or maybe about some parameters which may help?