Destroyed file system after adding disks to LVM on RAID5?
Just adding a bit of storage capacity on my Openmediavault storage server went wrong. What should I do to recover? Can you lead me?
This is what I did:
1 /dev/md2 raid5 set created, went well
2 /dev/md2 pv created, went well
3 /dev/md2 pv included in volume group datavg went well
4 creating a new file system in the logical volume datalv was not possible - no device available. I now know that only one fs per lv is possible, but was not aware of that when I tried this.
5 lvextend on datalv, went well - datalv now the full capacity including the new drives
6 creating a new file system in datalv still not possible - no device available.
7 trying fsgrow, allocated the entire capacity in one fell swoop - not what I wanted...
8 lvreduce on datalv to approx original capacity, went well
9 lvcreate data2lv, went well
10 creating the new file system in data2lv (XFS) this time, worked
After rebooting the system, the old file system (data) doesn't mount and there is no sign of the new (XFS) one.
I was wrong in the assumption that an lv can have more than one file system, so step 4 is when things started to go wrong. Step 5 was wrong too, but maybe reversible. Step 7 was a big mistake, since the file system can not be shrunk back. The rest of the steps still more wrong, but how can I fix this? Undo steps 8 to 10 and live with just one file system? I figured I should ask here before I mess things up worse.
I would be very grateful for some assistance on this,
/C
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=be85bbea-6e8b-4710-b1e0-894ad8d34d20 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=035fdb6b-e1bb-46c9-81c5-ff28840063c7 none            swap    sw              0       0
# >>> [openmediavault]
/dev/disk/by-label/data        /srv/dev-disk-by-label-data    ext4    defaults,nofail,user_xattr,noexec,usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0,acl    0 2
/dev/disk/by-uuid/035fdb6b-e1bb-46c9-81c5-ff28840063c7        /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-035fdb6b-e1bb-46c9-81c5-ff28840063c7    ext2    defaults,nofail,user_xattr,acl    0 2
/srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/data/        /export/data    none    bind,nofail    0 0
/srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/data/Backups/HomeAssistant/        /export/HAss    none    bind,nofail    0 0
/srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/data/Backups/LinHES/        /export/LinHES_backup    none    bind,nofail    0 0
/srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/data/LinHES/        /export/LinHES    none    bind,nofail    0 0
/srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/data/securitycams/        /export/securitycams    none    bind,nofail    0 0
# <<< [openmediavault] 





end of dmesg output:
[    7.009650] mpt2sas_cm0: handle(0x12) sas_address(0x5001e67958f53ffd) port_type(0x1)
[    7.010381] scsi 3:0:8:0: Enclosure         Intel    RES2SV240        0d00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    7.010385] scsi 3:0:8:0: set ignore_delay_remove for handle(0x0012)
[    7.010388] scsi 3:0:8:0: SES: handle(0x0012), sas_addr(0x5001e67958f53ffd), phy(24), device_name(0x0000000000000000)
[    7.010390] scsi 3:0:8:0: enclosure logical id (0x5001e67958f53fff), slot(24) 
[    7.010392] scsi 3:0:8:0: qdepth(254), tagged(1), scsi_level(6), cmd_que(1)
[    7.013166]  end_device-3:0:8: add: handle(0x0012), sas_addr(0x5001e67958f53ffd)
[    9.745705] mpt2sas_cm0: port enable: SUCCESS
[    9.747042] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      Corsair Force GS 5.07 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    9.747591] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      Corsair Force GS 5.07 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    9.750711] ohci-pci 0000:00:12.0: OHCI PCI host controller
[    9.750787] ohci-pci 0000:00:12.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 5
[    9.750831] ohci-pci 0000:00:12.0: irq 16, io mem 0xfe02e000
[    9.764544] ses 3:0:8:0: Attached Enclosure device
[    9.772078] sd 3:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[    9.772102] sd 3:0:1:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[    9.772361] sd 3:0:4:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[    9.772413] sd 3:0:5:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[    9.772487] sd 3:0:2:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[    9.772540] sd 3:0:7:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[    9.772555] sd 3:0:6:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[    9.772646] sd 3:0:3:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[    9.772671] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdi] 250069680 512-byte logical blocks: (128 GB/119 GiB)
[    9.772681] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdj] 250069680 512-byte logical blocks: (128 GB/119 GiB)
[    9.772686] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdi] Write Protect is off
[    9.772690] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdi] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    9.772697] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdj] Write Protect is off
[    9.772701] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdj] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    9.772708] sd 3:0:1:0: [sdb] 5860533168 512-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.73 TiB)
[    9.772709] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdi] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    9.772712] sd 3:0:1:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    9.772716] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] 5860533168 512-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.73 TiB)
[    9.772721] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    9.772724] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdj] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    9.772736] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdi] Preferred minimum I/O size 512 bytes
[    9.772757] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdj] Preferred minimum I/O size 512 bytes
[    9.773008] sd 3:0:2:0: [sdc] 7814037168 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.64 TiB)
[    9.773011] sd 3:0:2:0: [sdc] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    9.773135] sd 3:0:4:0: [sdd] 19532873728 512-byte logical blocks: (10.0 TB/9.10 TiB)
[    9.773137] sd 3:0:4:0: [sdd] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    9.773163] sd 3:0:3:0: [sde] 5860531055 512-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.73 TiB)
[    9.773165] sd 3:0:3:0: [sde] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    9.773188] sd 3:0:5:0: [sdf] 19532873728 512-byte logical blocks: (10.0 TB/9.10 TiB)
[    9.773190] sd 3:0:5:0: [sdf] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    9.773310] sd 3:0:6:0: [sdg] 19532873728 512-byte logical blocks: (10.0 TB/9.10 TiB)
[    9.773312] sd 3:0:6:0: [sdg] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    9.773556] sd 3:0:7:0: [sdh] 19532873728 512-byte logical blocks: (10.0 TB/9.10 TiB)
[    9.773559] sd 3:0:7:0: [sdh] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    9.774714] sd 3:0:7:0: [sdh] Write Protect is off
[    9.774717] sd 3:0:7:0: [sdh] Mode Sense: 7f 00 10 08
[    9.775773] sd 3:0:7:0: [sdh] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
[    9.776271] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    9.776275] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 7f 00 10 08
[    9.776336] sd 3:0:1:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    9.776341] sd 3:0:1:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 7f 00 10 08
[    9.776448]  sdj: sdj1 sdj2 sdj3
[    9.776475]  sdi: sdi1 sdi2 sdi3
[    9.776627] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdj] Attached SCSI disk
[    9.776662] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdi] Attached SCSI disk
[    9.776678] sd 3:0:4:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[    9.776681] sd 3:0:4:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 7f 00 10 08
[    9.776734] sd 3:0:5:0: [sdf] Write Protect is off
[    9.776737] sd 3:0:5:0: [sdf] Mode Sense: 7f 00 10 08
[    9.776872] sd 3:0:6:0: [sdg] Write Protect is off
[    9.776875] sd 3:0:6:0: [sdg] Mode Sense: 7f 00 10 08
[    9.777101] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
[    9.777171] sd 3:0:1:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
[    9.777195] sd 3:0:3:0: [sde] Write Protect is off
[    9.777198] sd 3:0:3:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 7f 00 10 08
[    9.777740] sd 3:0:4:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
[    9.777802] sd 3:0:5:0: [sdf] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
[    9.777908] sd 3:0:6:0: [sdg] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
[    9.778042] sd 3:0:3:0: [sde] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
[    9.792872] sd 3:0:7:0: [sdh] Attached SCSI disk
[    9.794058] sd 3:0:5:0: [sdf] Attached SCSI disk
[    9.797109] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    9.797304] sd 3:0:1:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[    9.799595] sd 3:0:6:0: [sdg] Attached SCSI disk
[    9.800877] sd 3:0:4:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
[    9.803440] sd 3:0:3:0: [sde] Attached SCSI disk
[    9.813710] usb usb5: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001, bcdDevice= 6.01
[    9.813714] usb usb5: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    9.813717] usb usb5: Product: OHCI PCI host controller
[    9.813719] usb usb5: Manufacturer: Linux 6.1.0-0.deb11.21-amd64 ohci_hcd
[    9.813720] usb usb5: SerialNumber: 0000:00:12.0
[    9.813858] hub 5-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    9.813868] hub 5-0:1.0: 3 ports detected
[    9.814196] ohci-pci 0000:00:12.1: OHCI PCI host controller
[    9.814206] ohci-pci 0000:00:12.1: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 6
[    9.814228] ohci-pci 0000:00:12.1: irq 16, io mem 0xfe02d000
[    9.854662] sd 3:0:2:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[    9.854671] sd 3:0:2:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 7f 00 10 08
[    9.855445] sd 3:0:2:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
[    9.877753] usb usb6: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001, bcdDevice= 6.01
[    9.877757] usb usb6: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    9.877760] usb usb6: Product: OHCI PCI host controller
[    9.877761] usb usb6: Manufacturer: Linux 6.1.0-0.deb11.21-amd64 ohci_hcd
[    9.877763] usb usb6: SerialNumber: 0000:00:12.1
[    9.877897] hub 6-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    9.877907] hub 6-0:1.0: 3 ports detected
[    9.878193] ohci-pci 0000:00:13.0: OHCI PCI host controller
[    9.878199] ohci-pci 0000:00:13.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 7
[    9.878250] ohci-pci 0000:00:13.0: irq 18, io mem 0xfe02b000
[    9.941747] usb usb7: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001, bcdDevice= 6.01
[    9.941751] usb usb7: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    9.941754] usb usb7: Product: OHCI PCI host controller
[    9.941755] usb usb7: Manufacturer: Linux 6.1.0-0.deb11.21-amd64 ohci_hcd
[    9.941757] usb usb7: SerialNumber: 0000:00:13.0
[    9.941879] hub 7-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    9.941889] hub 7-0:1.0: 3 ports detected
[    9.942167] ohci-pci 0000:00:13.1: OHCI PCI host controller
[    9.942173] ohci-pci 0000:00:13.1: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 8
[    9.942192] ohci-pci 0000:00:13.1: irq 18, io mem 0xfe02a000
[    9.946582] sd 3:0:2:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[    9.982793] md/raid1:md1: active with 2 out of 2 mirrors
[    9.982808] md/raid1:md126: active with 2 out of 2 mirrors
[    9.982863] md1: detected capacity change from 0 to 78124928
[    9.983036] md126: detected capacity change from 0 to 156227456
[   10.005696] usb usb8: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001, bcdDevice= 6.01
[   10.005702] usb usb8: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[   10.005704] usb usb8: Product: OHCI PCI host controller
[   10.005706] usb usb8: Manufacturer: Linux 6.1.0-0.deb11.21-amd64 ohci_hcd
[   10.005708] usb usb8: SerialNumber: 0000:00:13.1
[   10.005838] hub 8-0:1.0: USB hub found
[   10.005849] hub 8-0:1.0: 3 ports detected
[   10.006185] ohci-pci 0000:00:14.5: OHCI PCI host controller
[   10.006192] ohci-pci 0000:00:14.5: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 9
[   10.006214] ohci-pci 0000:00:14.5: irq 18, io mem 0xfe028000
[   10.053689] raid6: sse2x4   gen()  7753 MB/s
[   10.073706] usb usb9: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001, bcdDevice= 6.01
[   10.073711] usb usb9: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[   10.073714] usb usb9: Product: OHCI PCI host controller
[   10.073716] usb usb9: Manufacturer: Linux 6.1.0-0.deb11.21-amd64 ohci_hcd
[   10.073718] usb usb9: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.5
[   10.073851] hub 9-0:1.0: USB hub found
[   10.073862] hub 9-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[   10.121687] raid6: sse2x2   gen()  7627 MB/s
[   10.189688] raid6: sse2x1   gen()  6191 MB/s
[   10.189691] raid6: using algorithm sse2x4 gen() 7753 MB/s
[   10.257685] raid6: .... xor() 3661 MB/s, rmw enabled
[   10.257687] raid6: using ssse3x2 recovery algorithm
[   10.258670] xor: automatically using best checksumming function   avx       
[   10.259422] async_tx: api initialized (async)
[   10.271440] md/raid:md0: device sde operational as raid disk 3
[   10.271444] md/raid:md0: device sdb operational as raid disk 1
[   10.271445] md/raid:md0: device sda operational as raid disk 0
[   10.271446] md/raid:md0: device sdc operational as raid disk 2
[   10.271465] md/raid:md2: device sdf operational as raid disk 1
[   10.271469] md/raid:md2: device sdh operational as raid disk 3
[   10.271471] md/raid:md2: device sdg operational as raid disk 2
[   10.271472] md/raid:md2: device sdd operational as raid disk 0
[   10.272715] md/raid:md0: raid level 5 active with 4 out of 4 devices, algorithm 2
[   10.272728] md/raid:md2: raid level 5 active with 4 out of 4 devices, algorithm 2
[   10.274723] md2: detected capacity change from 0 to 58597828608
[   10.302716] md0: detected capacity change from 0 to 17580797952
[   10.314506] usb 5-2: new full-speed USB device number 2 using ohci-pci
[   10.351344] random: crng init done
[   10.478717] device-mapper: core: CONFIG_IMA_DISABLE_HTABLE is disabled. Duplicate IMA measurements will not be recorded in the IMA log.
[   10.478750] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[   10.478830] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.47.0-ioctl (2022-07-28) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[   10.524723] usb 5-2: New USB device found, idVendor=051d, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 1.06
[   10.524729] usb 5-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   10.524731] usb 5-2: Product: Smart-UPS 1000 FW:UPS 09.3 / ID=18
[   10.524733] usb 5-2: Manufacturer: American Power Conversion 
[   10.524734] usb 5-2: SerialNumber: AS1707331537  
[   10.535479] hid: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[   10.544453] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[   10.544456] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[   10.546915] hid-generic 0003:051D:0003.0001: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.00 Device [American Power Conversion  Smart-UPS 1000 FW:UPS 09.3 / ID=18] on usb-0000:00:12.0-2/input0
[   11.087936] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-intel, zoned=yes, fsverity=yes
[   41.958600] EXT4-fs (md126): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
[   42.013214] Not activating Mandatory Access Control as /sbin/tomoyo-init does not exist.
[   42.090393] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'autofs4'
[   42.115930] systemd[1]: systemd 247.3-7+deb11u6 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +ZSTD +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=unified)
[   42.116051] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[   42.116543] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <bolivar>.
[   42.306079] systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/clamav-onaccess.service:13: Standard output type syslog is obsolete, automatically updating to journal. Please update your unit file, and consider removing the setting altogether.
[   42.306476] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/clamav-freshclam.service:11: Standard output type syslog is obsolete, automatically updating to journal. Please update your unit file, and consider removing the setting altogether.
[   42.307153] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/clamav-daemon.service:12: Standard output type syslog is obsolete, automatically updating to journal. Please update your unit file, and consider removing the setting altogether.
[   42.312038] systemd[1]: Queued start job for default target Graphical Interface.
[   42.330323] systemd[1]: Created slice system-getty.slice.
[   42.330620] systemd[1]: Created slice system-modprobe.slice.
[   42.330854] systemd[1]: Created slice system-postfix.slice.
[   42.331079] systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
[   42.331305] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[   42.331368] systemd[1]: Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
[   42.331420] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[   42.331575] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[   42.331608] systemd[1]: Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes.
[   42.331652] systemd[1]: Reached target Paths.
[   42.331680] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[   42.331703] systemd[1]: Reached target System Time Set.
[   42.331781] systemd[1]: Listening on Device-mapper event daemon FIFOs.
[   42.331874] systemd[1]: Listening on LVM2 poll daemon socket.
[   42.336222] systemd[1]: Listening on RPCbind Server Activation Socket.
[   42.336356] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[   42.336470] systemd[1]: Listening on fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
[   42.336541] systemd[1]: Listening on initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[   42.336712] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[   42.336827] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[   42.336946] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[   42.337078] systemd[1]: Listening on Network Service Netlink Socket.
[   42.337484] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[   42.337575] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[   42.338502] systemd[1]: Mounting Huge Pages File System...
[   42.339406] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[   42.340365] systemd[1]: Mounting NFSD configuration filesystem...
[   42.341305] systemd[1]: Mounting RPC Pipe File System...
[   42.342485] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Debug File System...
[   42.343458] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Trace File System...
[   42.343588] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Kernel Module supporting RPCSEC_GSS being skipped.
[   42.343753] systemd[1]: Finished Availability of block devices.
[   42.345380] systemd[1]: Starting Set the console keyboard layout...
[   42.346510] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel...
[   42.347606] systemd[1]: Starting Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling...
[   42.348989] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module configfs...
[   42.350348] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module drm...
[   42.351388] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module fuse...
[   42.351481] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in OpenVSwitch configuration for cleanup being skipped.
[   42.352694] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Set Up Additional Binary Formats being skipped.
[   42.352730] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in File System Check on Root Device being skipped.
[   42.354950] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[   42.357137] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[   42.358386] systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
[   42.359555] systemd[1]: Starting Coldplug All udev Devices...
[   42.362006] systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[   42.362148] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[   42.362262] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Debug File System.
[   42.362373] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Trace File System.
[   42.362841] systemd[1]: Finished Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel.
[   42.363275] systemd[1]: modprobe@configfs.service: Succeeded.
[   42.363694] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module configfs.
[   42.364942] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Configuration File System...
[   42.368675] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Modules.
[   42.368852] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Configuration File System.
[   42.370036] systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
[   42.370843] fuse: init (API version 7.37)
[   42.371752] systemd[1]: modprobe@fuse.service: Succeeded.
[   42.372144] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module fuse.
[   42.373401] systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
[   42.376648] systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
[   42.383402] systemd[1]: Finished Apply Kernel Variables.
[   42.384015] EXT4-fs (md126): re-mounted. Quota mode: none.
[   42.385366] systemd[1]: Finished Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
[   42.387332] systemd[1]: Starting Initial Check File System Quotas...
[   42.387952] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
[   42.388047] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Platform Persistent Storage Archival being skipped.
[   42.389092] systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
[   42.390273] systemd[1]: Starting Create System Users...
[   42.406816] systemd[1]: Finished Load/Save Random Seed.
[   42.408709] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in First Boot Complete being skipped.
[   42.410165] systemd[1]: Finished Create System Users.
[   42.412453] systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
[   42.418172] systemd[1]: Finished Initial Check File System Quotas.
[   42.429120] systemd[1]: Finished Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
[   42.430906] systemd[1]: Starting Rule-based Manager for Device Events and Files...
[   42.436223] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[   42.436227] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[   42.436228] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[   42.436229] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[   42.449951] ACPI: bus type drm_connector registered
[   42.450404] systemd[1]: Mounted RPC Pipe File System.
[   42.451406] systemd[1]: Starting pNFS block layout mapping daemon...
[   42.451934] systemd[1]: modprobe@drm.service: Succeeded.
[   42.452283] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module drm.
[   42.454355] systemd[1]: Started pNFS block layout mapping daemon.
[   42.466920] systemd[1]: Started Rule-based Manager for Device Events and Files.
[   42.468985] systemd[1]: Starting Network Service...
[   42.482992] systemd[1]: Finished Set the console keyboard layout.
[   42.507752] systemd[1]: Finished Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling.
[   42.507870] systemd[1]: Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
[   42.539579] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[   42.553503] acpi_cpufreq: overriding BIOS provided _PSD data
[   42.561672] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[   42.565078] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1
[   42.568531] ACPI: button: Power Button [PWRB]
[   42.568874] sd 3:0:1:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[   42.570834] sd 3:0:2:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[   42.574606] sd 3:0:3:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[   42.576518] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
[   42.576551] sd 3:0:4:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[   42.577588] sd 3:0:5:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
[   42.584095] sd 3:0:6:0: Attached scsi generic sg6 type 0
[   42.592174] ACPI: button: Power Button [PWRF]
[   42.595542] sd 3:0:7:0: Attached scsi generic sg7 type 0
[   42.595748] r8169 0000:04:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware rtl_nic/rtl8168g-2.fw
[   42.596555] ses 3:0:8:0: Attached scsi generic sg8 type 13
[   42.596684] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg9 type 0
[   42.599088] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg10 type 0
[   42.604298] input: PC Speaker as /devices/platform/pcspkr/input/input3
[   42.615393] systemd-journald[798]: Received client request to flush runtime journal.
[   42.619045] sp5100_tco: SP5100/SB800 TCO WatchDog Timer Driver
[   42.621719] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-0-400:00: attached PHY driver (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-0-400:00, irq=MAC)
[   42.642344] sp5100-tco sp5100-tco: Failed to reserve MMIO or alternate MMIO region
[   42.642395] sp5100-tco: probe of sp5100-tco failed with error -16
[   42.655985] cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
[   42.685219] AVX version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[   42.685272] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[   42.800800] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:05.1/sound/card0/input4
[   42.818231] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: Link is Down
[   42.888925] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[   42.889075] radeon 0000:01:05.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[   42.889633] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
[   42.889920] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (RS780 0x1002:0x9616 0x1458:0xD000 0x00).
[   42.890569] ATOM BIOS: B27732
[   42.890585] radeon 0000:01:05.0: VRAM: 512M 0x00000000C0000000 - 0x00000000DFFFFFFF (512M used)
[   42.890590] radeon 0000:01:05.0: GTT: 512M 0x00000000A0000000 - 0x00000000BFFFFFFF
[   42.890598] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=512M, BAR=256M
[   42.890600] [drm] RAM width 32bits DDR
[   42.890629] [drm] radeon: 512M of VRAM memory ready
[   42.890632] [drm] radeon: 512M of GTT memory ready.
[   42.890641] [drm] Loading RS780 Microcode
[   42.893910] radeon 0000:01:05.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/RS780_pfp.bin
[   42.894752] radeon 0000:01:05.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/RS780_me.bin
[   42.896489] radeon 0000:01:05.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/R600_rlc.bin
[   42.896503] [drm] radeon: power management initialized
[   42.896507] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 131072, num gpu pages 131072
[   42.915405] [drm] PCIE GART of 512M enabled (table at 0x00000000C0040000).
[   42.915440] radeon 0000:01:05.0: WB enabled
[   42.915445] radeon 0000:01:05.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x00000000a0000c00
[   42.919478] radeon 0000:01:05.0: radeon: MSI limited to 32-bit
[   42.919495] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[   42.950634] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 1 usecs
[   42.950879] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   42.951901] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
[   42.951903] [drm] Connector 0:
[   42.951905] [drm]   VGA-1
[   42.951906] [drm]   DDC: 0x7e40 0x7e40 0x7e44 0x7e44 0x7e48 0x7e48 0x7e4c 0x7e4c
[   42.951909] [drm]   Encoders:
[   42.951909] [drm]     CRT1: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_DAC1
[   42.951911] [drm] Connector 1:
[   42.951912] [drm]   DVI-D-1
[   42.951912] [drm]   HPD1
[   42.951913] [drm]   DDC: 0x7e50 0x7e50 0x7e54 0x7e54 0x7e58 0x7e58 0x7e5c 0x7e5c
[   42.951915] [drm]   Encoders:
[   42.951916] [drm]     DFP1: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_LVTMA
[   42.968693] [drm] fb mappable at 0xD0141000
[   42.968699] [drm] vram apper at 0xD0000000
[   42.968701] [drm] size 3145728
[   42.968704] [drm] fb depth is 24
[   42.968705] [drm]    pitch is 4096
[   42.968809] fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   42.993990] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 128x48
[   42.994982] radeon 0000:01:05.0: [drm] fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
[   43.035372] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.50.0 20080528 for 0000:01:05.0 on minor 0
[   43.064106] EXT4-fs (md1): mounting ext2 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[   43.099664] EXT4-fs (md1): mounted filesystem without journal. Quota mode: none.
[   43.197238] EXT4-fs (dm-0): bad geometry: block count 9522326528 exceeds size of device (2856698880 blocks)
[   43.413872] SVM: TSC scaling supported
[   43.413877] kvm: Nested Virtualization enabled
[   43.413879] SVM: kvm: Nested Paging enabled
[   43.413890] SVM: LBR virtualization supported
[   43.429597] MCE: In-kernel MCE decoding enabled.
[   45.391715] [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
[   45.391813] amdgpu: CRAT table not found
[   45.391816] amdgpu: Virtual CRAT table created for CPU
[   45.391832] amdgpu: Topology: Add CPU node
[   45.737903] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[   45.737917] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp4s0: link becomes ready
[   46.720565] NFSD: Using UMH upcall client tracking operations.
[   46.720571] NFSD: starting 90-second grace period (net f0000000)
[  136.827116] EXT4-fs (dm-0): bad geometry: block count 9522326528 exceeds size of device (2856698880 blocks)
[135143.417824] md: data-check of RAID array md1
[135143.489597] md: delaying data-check of md126 until md1 has finished (they share one or more physical units)
[135340.210882] md: md1: data-check done.
[135340.217461] md: data-check of RAID array md126
[135761.486563] md: md126: data-check done.
root@bolivar:/# 


Well, that's a lot of question marks. If mkfs did not actually go through at all (what do you mean by fail, what was the error message, ...?), and if mount now simply complains about the device size (mount error in journalctl, dmesg?), you might still have a chance. It could be as simple as providing a device of the required size. Otherwise, if mkfs went through, it'll be a ton more complicated, and if the device was trim/discarded even utterly impossible to recover.

"creating a new file system in the logical volume datalv failed" - What happened? What error message(s) did you get? (Why did you proceed if you got an error?)

"Failed" was a bad description. What happened when trying to create a file system, was that there was no device available in the list. It was not possible to even attempt.

So ⅔ of filesystem missing. If that was an empty grow, and you did not shrink it by too much, then debugfs might be able to recover your files, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/742453/30851 (rest of the answer probably does not apply to you). Recovering more might be difficult since (if I understand correctly) you already reassigned and formatted that space. You'd have to roll back LVM changes to make the attempt (since there is no guarantee where LVM allocates its extents, so simply making it larger again might allocate them in the wrong place).

I see no reference to an XFS file system in dmesg or anywhere else (step109. Hopefully, it was never created? Rolling back the LVM changes, would that mean deleting data2lv (step9) and restoring datalv back to the maximum capacity (step 8) as it was before I ruined it?

old answer on LVM metadata backups

Please update your question with the new information. It's hard enough to read with all the images as it is. Don't make it any harder by spreading information across the question and these comments

@frostschutz The LVM metadata backups are all there. It would be tempting to restore to step5. Restoring to step7 would match the latest size of the file system. Would that be a safer bet?

If you don't mind sharing, you can post them all somewhere and I'll take a look? In particular, the original size before this mess happened, the full size you'd have to restore, and the current state.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LZacST-Q3hYXkDN4doLVZ1vK41QfZ6FI?usp=sharing

OK, so according to your metadata, the sequence of events was:
vgextend datavg /dev/md2
lvextend --extents 100%VG /dev/mapper/datavg-datalv
# guess the datalv filesystem was grown here
lvreduce --extents 30%VG /dev/mapper/datavg-datalv --force
lvcreate --name data2lv --extents 50%VG datavg
# guess the data2lv filesystem was created here
lvreduce --extents 30%VG /dev/mapper/datavg-data2lv --force

If so, the lvreduce commands made both filesystems inaccessible (device smaller than the filesystem believes it to be).
If data2lv was empty anyway, you can remove it directly:
lvremove datavg/data2lv

(If data2lv had any data you want to keep, you'd have to restore its original size first, then transfer it somewhere else.)
Restoring original size, for datavg/datalv, after data2lv was removed.
According to metadata, this is datalv current layout:
[…]
segment_count = 2

segment1 {
    start_extent = 0
    extent_count = 2146093  # 8.1867 Terabytes

    type = "striped"
    stripe_count = 1    # linear

    stripes = [
        "pv0", 0
    ]
}
segment2 {
    start_extent = 2146093
    extent_count = 643652   # 2.45534 Terabytes

    type = "striped"
    stripe_count = 1    # linear

    stripes = [
        "pv1", 0
    ]
}
[…]

And this is the change you want to achieve:
[…]
segment2 {
    start_extent = 2146093
    extent_count = 7153054  # 27.2867 Terabytes

    type = "striped"
    stripe_count = 1    # linear

    stripes = [
        "pv1", 0
    ]
}
[…]

So what needs to be added is pv1:643652-7153053.
Where pv0, pv1 refer to these physical volumes:
pv0 {
    id = "I2RWJZ-s9Rv-kZlC-jSTG-BFII-ZeK8-0JS1rL"
    device = "/dev/md0" # Hint only
    […]
    pe_count = 2146093  # 8.1867 Terabytes
}

pv1 {
    id = "WldN1d-SmhW-u9cB-PDOD-W7fE-j7gP-56Wc9d"
    device = "/dev/md2" # Hint only
    […]
    pe_count = 7153054  # 27.2867 Terabytes
}

So you can try your luck with this command:
lvextend datavg/datalv /dev/disk/by-id/lvm-pv-uuid-WldN1d-SmhW-u9cB-PDOD-W7fE-j7gP-56Wc9d:643652-7153053

And then verify the segments in metadata afterwards.
This is actually the simplest case. There is no segment fragmentation or reordering going on. It's just a linear extension within the same PV. So simply running lvextend -l+100%FREE datavg/datalv should also work here.

Now, can you recover your datalv filesystem at this point?
It depends. Technically you corrupted it by creating a new filesystem in data2lv, overwriting extents that still belonged to the filesystem in datalv.
However if no files or metadata were ever written in that area after growing, it might just have survived this. With any luck, mount will just work at this point.
If you then still want to shrink it, you'll have to do it properly with e2fsck, resize2fs, or let LVM handle it with lvreduce --fs resize (or lvreduce --resizefs for older versions of LVM). Don't use --force or ignore options unless you're really sure your filesystem is safe…

Deleting data2lv, expanding datalv to the max size in the GUI and a restart solved this. As you know, there is no backup that's good enough, so your help here, @frostschutz, was extremely valuable. Thanks for taking the time and your friendly way of holding my hand through this!
