mdadm RAID5 array became "active, FAILED" and now no longer mounts
Today my RAID5 array status from mdadm --detail /dev/md0 became active, FAILED (I have mobile notifications setup)
Most of the files were present but some were missing. This happened before and I solved it by rebooting the machine (I think the status was different tho)
No luck this time, now the RAID no longer works
Here are some details about my setup:
mdadm --detail /dev/md0

/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
        Raid Level : raid5
     Total Devices : 4
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

             State : inactive
   Working Devices : 4

              Name : RHomeServer:0  (local to host RHomeServer)
              UUID : d88446ae:f9f5c759:b4ac531c:933f8c62
            Events : 104300

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8       64        -        /dev/sde
       -       8       32        -        /dev/sdc
       -       8       48        -        /dev/sdd
       -       8       16        -        /dev/sdb

cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf

ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=RHomeServer:0 UUID=d88446ae:f9f5c759:b4ac531c:933f8c62

sudo blkid | grep sd

/dev/sdd: UUID="d88446ae-f9f5-c759-b4ac-531c933f8c62" UUID_SUB="ce9975e7-ec99-8630-acad-b3d090287950" LABEL="RHomeServer:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdb: UUID="d88446ae-f9f5-c759-b4ac-531c933f8c62" UUID_SUB="f20836f9-8960-0b38-e1c3-ea22cba58014" LABEL="RHomeServer:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sde: UUID="d88446ae-f9f5-c759-b4ac-531c933f8c62" UUID_SUB="d49ff5be-6b1b-8e8d-26b1-52e90bb05ce2" LABEL="RHomeServer:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdc: UUID="d88446ae-f9f5-c759-b4ac-531c933f8c62" UUID_SUB="863075ad-9e12-6cfd-3dbf-35017b1f408d" LABEL="RHomeServer:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"

mdadm --examine /dev/sd[b-e]

/dev/sdb:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : d88446ae:f9f5c759:b4ac531c:933f8c62
           Name : RHomeServer:0  (local to host RHomeServer)
  Creation Time : Thu Aug 10 16:54:57 2023
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 35156391936 sectors (16.37 TiB 18.00 TB)
     Array Size : 52734587904 KiB (49.11 TiB 54.00 TB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264096 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : f20836f9:89600b38:e1c3ea22:cba58014

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Tue Jul 16 18:13:26 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 80 sectors
       Checksum : dd7e994d - correct
         Events : 104300

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : spare
   Array State : .... ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

/dev/sdc:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : d88446ae:f9f5c759:b4ac531c:933f8c62
           Name : RHomeServer:0  (local to host RHomeServer)
  Creation Time : Thu Aug 10 16:54:57 2023
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 35156391936 sectors (16.37 TiB 18.00 TB)
     Array Size : 52734587904 KiB (49.11 TiB 54.00 TB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264096 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 863075ad:9e126cfd:3dbf3501:7b1f408d

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Tue Jul 16 18:13:26 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 80 sectors
       Checksum : ae28e804 - correct
         Events : 104300

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : spare
   Array State : .... ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

/dev/sdd:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : d88446ae:f9f5c759:b4ac531c:933f8c62
           Name : RHomeServer:0  (local to host RHomeServer)
  Creation Time : Thu Aug 10 16:54:57 2023
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 35156391936 sectors (16.37 TiB 18.00 TB)
     Array Size : 52734587904 KiB (49.11 TiB 54.00 TB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264096 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : ce9975e7:ec998630:acadb3d0:90287950

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Tue Jul 16 18:13:26 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 80 sectors
       Checksum : adfad01f - correct
         Events : 104300

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : spare
   Array State : .... ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

/dev/sde:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : d88446ae:f9f5c759:b4ac531c:933f8c62
           Name : RHomeServer:0  (local to host RHomeServer)
  Creation Time : Thu Aug 10 16:54:57 2023
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 35156391936 sectors (16.37 TiB 18.00 TB)
     Array Size : 52734587904 KiB (49.11 TiB 54.00 TB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264096 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : d49ff5be:6b1b8e8d:26b152e9:0bb05ce2

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Tue Jul 16 18:13:26 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 80 sectors
       Checksum : 8d04e29c - correct
         Events : 104300

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : spare
   Array State : .... ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

cat /proc/mdstat

Personalities : [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
unused devices: <none>

The drives seem healthy, no SMART issues
I tried running mdadm --assemble --scan but I get
mdadm: /dev/md0 assembled from 0 drives and 4 spares - not enough to start the array.

mdadm: failed to RUN_ARRAY /dev/md0: Invalid argument
mdadm: Not enough devices to start the array.

The exact same for mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde and with/without the flags --run --force
I'm running Ubuntu 24.10, everything up to date including kernel 6.9.9
What can I do to recover my array?
I've read about doing
mdadm --stop /dev/md0
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde
mdadm --create --assume-clean /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde

but I'm afraid that if I lose my data I also break any other recovery attempt.

The drives no longer remember their device role (which order the drives were in). At this point mdadm create is indeed your only (final) hope. Some pitfalls to look out for: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131927/30851

Felt lucky and risked it all!
I wanted to make sure about the HDD order so I ran
sudo blkid | grep sd

So based on the UUID_SUB values, the likely order of the drives is:
/dev/sdb (UUID_SUB="f20836f9-8960-0b38-e1c3-ea22cba58014")
/dev/sdc (UUID_SUB="863075ad-9e12-6cfd-3dbf-35017b1f408d")
/dev/sdd (UUID_SUB="ce9975e7-ec99-8630-acad-b3d090287950")
/dev/sde (UUID_SUB="d49ff5be-6b1b-8e8d-26b1-52e90bb05ce2")

From what I've read online, this order is derived from the lexicographical sorting of the UUID_SUB values, which often corresponds to the order in which the drives were added to the array.
so I went ahead and ran:
mdadm --stop /dev/md0
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde
mdadm --create --assume-clean /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde

My array is now fixed and mounted!
